# arrows in tikzcd that are not aligned correctly

Tags: tikz-arrows, tikz-cd

```
\documentclass[12pt,reqno,a4paper]{amsart}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % not needed with up-to-date TeX systems
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{color}

\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem} % do you *really* need it?
\usepackage{datetime}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\theoremstyle{definition}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{construction}{Construction}[section]
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}[section]
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}[section]
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}[section]
\newtheorem{example}{Example}
\newtheorem*{question}{Question}
\newtheorem*{solution}{Solution}
\newtheorem{exercise}{Exercise} 

\newcommand{\mc}{\mathcal}
\newcommand{\mf}{\mathfrak}
\newcommand{\mb}{\mathbb}
\newcommand{\xra}{\xrightarrow}
\newcommand{\ra}{\rightarrow}
\newcommand{\rra}{\rightrightarrows}
\pagestyle{myheadings}

\textheight 9.3in 
\textwidth 6.5in
\calclayout

% metadata

%\date{\today}


\title{Something}
\author{Someone} 

\begin{document}

\[\begin{tikzcd}
0 \arrow[r] & A \arrow[rr] \arrow[dd] &   & B \arrow[rr] \arrow[dd] & & C \arrow[r] \arrow[dd] & 0 \\
D \arrow[dd] \arrow[ru,xshift=0.75ex,"t"]
\arrow[ru,xshift=-0.75ex,"s"'] &                             & E \arrow[ru,xshift=0.75ex,"t"]
\arrow[ru,xshift=-0.75ex,"s"'] \arrow[dd] &                             & F \arrow[ru,xshift=0.75ex,"t"]
\arrow[ru,xshift=-0.75ex,"s"'] \arrow[dd] &                           &   \\
& G                        &                                & H                         &                               & I                       &   \\
J \arrow[ru,xshift=0.75ex,"t"]
\arrow[ru,xshift=-0.75ex,"s"']                 &                             & K \arrow[ru,xshift=0.75ex,"t"]
\arrow[ru,xshift=-0.75ex,"s"']                 &                             & L \arrow[ru,xshift=0.75ex,"t"]
\arrow[ru,xshift=-0.75ex,"s"']                &                           &  
\end{tikzcd}\]

\end{document}
```

Above is the minimal working example.

I want arrows from D to A, E to B, F to C and other such arrows to start and end at same, just like what you get when you use "\rightrightarrows".

How do I do that? Any comments are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `shift left` and `shift right` rather than `xshift`.

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,reqno,a4paper]{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{tikzcd}
0 \arrow[r] & A \arrow[rr] \arrow[dd] && B \arrow[rr] \arrow[dd] && C \arrow[r] \arrow[dd] & 0
\\
D \arrow[ru,shift right=0.75ex,"s"'] \arrow[ru,shift left=0.75ex,"t"] \arrow[dd] &&
E \arrow[ru,shift right=0.75ex,"s"'] \arrow[ru,shift left=0.75ex,"t"] \arrow[dd] &&
F \arrow[ru,shift right=0.75ex,"s"'] \arrow[ru,shift left=0.75ex,"t"] \arrow[dd]
\\
& G && H && I
\\
J \arrow[ru,shift right=0.75ex,"s"'] \arrow[ru,shift left=0.75ex,"t"] &&
K \arrow[ru,shift right=0.75ex,"s"'] \arrow[ru,shift left=0.75ex,"t"] &&
L \arrow[ru,shift right=0.75ex,"s"'] \arrow[ru,shift left=0.75ex,"t"]
\end{tikzcd}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: you are making my life easier :)